# Basic modular arithmetic question

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If for two integers $a,b$, $a=b \mod x$, what is $x$ in terms of $a$ and $b$?.

I think the answer is $a-b$, but I'm not sure how to prove it without modular arithmetic, which I don't really understand.

Is there a simple way to prove and this without mods?

Answer (score 1):

This follows directly from the definition of congruence with respect to modular arithmetic (there's not much you need to know):

$$a \equiv b \pmod{x} \;\;\; \Leftrightarrow \;\;\; x | (a-b)$$

(This latter expression, if you're not familiar, just means "$x$ evenly divides $(a-b)$," or, equivalently, "$(a-b)$ has no remainder when divided by $x$.")

The problem is that, in reality, this means that, for some integer $k$,

$$\frac{a-b}{x} = k \;\;\; \Leftrightarrow \;\;\; x = \frac{a-b}{k}$$

To say that $x = a-b$ (i.e. that $k=1$) means that there's some sort of context we're missing that would apply in this context. As presented, however, I think this is as far as one can get.

Comment: Use `\pmod{x}` to get $a\equiv b \pmod{x}$. `\bmod`, will produce the binary operator: `b\bmod x` produces $b\bmod x$. What you want to avoid is `\mod`, because the spacing is wrong.

Comment: I just was straight up using \text{mod}, but noted.

Comment: The three different modular commands are the second most common LaTeX mistake people make, I try to spread the knowledge where I can. (The most common is to use `<` and `>` instead of `\langle` and `\rangle`)

Comment: Thanks! I think a better phrasing is "If two integers a,b have the same remainder when divided by x, what is x in terms of a and b?" I think I used the mod wrong, sorry!

Comment: I honestly just don't know much LaTeX, really. Most of what I know is self-taught or seen from experience, like using WYSIWYG editors and such. This site has at least been helpful in improving my LaTeX lol